# How do I request permission to dock my ship?

Tags: elite-dangerous

The latest update has added the ability to dock with a starport in Zelada, however, I can't seem to work out how exactly I'm supposed to dock. Approaching the station results in a warning that I do not have permission to land and I'm seeing no option in the controls that will allow me to communicate with the station to request permission to dock.

[image]

How do I request permission to dock my ship aboard the Corolis Starport in Zelada?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To dock you will need to request permission by selecting the station in the contacts pane in navigation and then select "Request Docking":

[image]

This will give you a designated dock to land in and a time limit for docking permission.

Comment: Once the comms panel is open, what button do you press to bring up this lock target/request docking dialog?

Comment: on the keyboard, Q and E cycle between tabs in the left screen so you can get to dock permission request. This took me a long time to find also.